# Объём понятия "кабина"

Tags: лексика

Хотелось бы уточнить смысл понятия "кабина". Во всяком транспорте место, выделенное водителю, может называться кабиной? Одно из значений "будка специального назначения". Можно ли кабиной посчитать телефонную будку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Хотелось бы уточнить смысл понятия "кабина".**

Пожалуйста. Для этих целей лучше всего подходят толковые словари. Например, [словарь Кузнецова](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&all=x):

> **КАБИНА**, -ы; ж. [франц. cabine]. Небольшое   помещение специального назначения. *К. лифта. К. для  голосования. К. для телефонных
>   переговоров. К.  душа.* || Передний отсек автомобиля, самолёта, экскаватора и т.п., оборудованный для его управления.

**Во всяком транспорте место, выделенное водителю, может называться кабиной?**

Нет. Например, на велосипедах, в лодках, на гужевом транспорте и т.п. место водителя не принято называть кабиной. Вероятно, потому, что оно недостаточно похоже на специальное помещение или "отсек, оборудованный для управления".

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку существует [фотокабина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0), то и телефонную будку можно назвать телефонной кабиной. В литературе такое название [используется](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Более того, похоже, что "телефонная кабина" и есть [техническое название телефонной будки](http://kombitel.ru/catalog/frame/~ne-vyibran-kabina-telefonnaya-shumoizoliruyuschaya-ktsh/).